# Laravel - check account status when Perform post request

Tags: php, laravel

in my user table I have a active_id column to track this user account is still active or not.

Is it possible when a logged in user visit our website, check if it's not a active user then logout the logged in user.

Or when the logged in inactive user perform a post request , log out the user immediately .

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this very easily with `Middleware`

- Do the console command `php artisan make:middleware CheckUserIsActive`
- Go to the generated file at `app/Http/Middlewares/CheckUserIsActive`
- In the handle method

  ```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      if (! $user = auth()->user()->is_active) {
          auth()->user()->logout();
      }
      return $next($request);
  }
  ```
- Edit the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file: find `web` key on `middlewareGroups` property and append your new middleware `\App\Http\Middlewares\CheckUserIsActive::class,`

With this approach the check will be fired off on each request on your app, assuming that in your routes.php file you have `web` group middleware applied to all your routes, which is the case if you installed laravel and didn't change it.

Take a closer look at middlewares in the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware)

---

Also note, that this will work only when there is an authenticated user. If there isn't then `auth()->user()` will return `null` and you'll get and error like 'Trying to call method logout() on null'. To avoid this error you need to make sure that there is an authenticated user and only then check if he's active. To do so Laravel provides built in `auth` middleware. Just append it to the `middlewaresGroups`'s `web` key before your own middleware.

But again this is to work if it's fit your projects needs. If you do require user to be authenticated to go to any of the pages of your app then do this approach. if not - you need to limit some requests to be filtered by middlewares. Again, you may find this on docs or ask here if needed, I'll provide samples